# $f(x)=A\tan(x+a)$ - does the set of these functions constitute a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I know that I need to check whether or not $A_1\tan(x+a_1)+A_2\tan(x+a_2)=A_3\tan(x+a_3)$, but I have no idea how to prove it, $\tan(x+a)=\dfrac{\tan(x)+\tan(a)}{1-\tan(x)\tan(a)}$ doesn't help.

Comment: If you think the answer by @Gaberial Romon has solved your problem, please click that "check mark" to accept it. Otherwise, it is clogging the system. Thank you.

Comment: If you think the given answer is not helpful, please make some comments beneath to let people know how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Not true. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there exists $A$ and $a$ such that for all $x$, $\tan(x)+\tan(x+1)=A\tan(x+a)$.

Taking derivatives on both sides, $$\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{1+(x+1)^2}=\frac{A}{1+(x+a)^2}$$

Multiplying both sides by $x^2$ and letting $x$ go to $\infty$, one gets $2=A$.

Plugging in $x=-a$, one gets $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+a^2}+\frac{1}{1+(1-a)^2}=2$.

It remains to note (or prove) that the function $\displaystyle a\mapsto \frac{1}{1+a^2}+\frac{1}{1+(1-a)^2}$ is always less than $1.6$ to get a contradiction.